# After Python2 upgrade, windows launcher no longer runs Python3 / reads shebang line

Tags: python, shebang

Python 2.7.4 has been on my Windows 7 box for a while.  All good.  About
two weeks ago I installed 3.6.4, also all good.  I was able to control which 
version ran using the hash-bang first line:

```
#!/bin/Python27/python 
or:  
#!/bin/Python36/python
```

All my files are named with a .py extension:  script.py

This morning I upgraded 2.7.4 to 2.7.13.  Now Python2 runs always, regardless
of what I put in the first line of my script, including swapping slashes to
Windows convention and prepending C, C:, \C, \C: to the path.

Any suggestions?